# Can I only get some columns not all column from ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem when I use ASP.NET Core Web API. Can you help me?

I do not want to get all columns from the API, I only want to get some columns from database.

I do not know how to write the LINQ query.

Thanks

```
// GET: api/device
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<device>>> Getdevice()
{
    return await _context.device.Select(c => c.barcode_1).ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options. Select an anonymous type or a viewmodel.

With an anonymous type, you simply select the propertys you want to return:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDevices()
{
    var result = await _context.device
                         .Select(c => new {
                               Barcode = c.barcode_1,
                               Id = c.Id,
                               Foo = c.Foo,
                         })
                         .ToListAsync();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

When you decide to create a view model, you create DTO class or record, with the properties you need first, and then select and return that type in your query:

```cs
public record DeviceViewModel(int Id, string Barcode, int Foo);

//OR

public class DeviceViewModel
{
    public int Id {get; init;}
    public string Barcode {get; init;}
    public int Foo {get; init;}
}
```

The selection in your query looks almost the same, but instead of an anonymous object, you now select an object of type `DeviceViewModel`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDevices()
{
    var result = await _context.device
                         .Select(c => new DeviceViewModel {
                               Barcode = c.barcode_1,
                               Id = c.Id,
                               Foo = c.Foo,
                         })
                         .ToListAsync();
    return Ok(result);
}
```